# Move custom cells to right in UITableView in editing mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a multisectioned `UITableView` and it contains custom cells which are consist of `UIImage`, `UILabel` etc. When I click edit button on navigation bar, I want the cell contents to move to the right side. Because I want to prevent overlap between "delete" visual and my custom cell's `UIImage`. Also I want it to revert back when editing mode ended.

I tried `setIndentationLevel` but it didn't work. How can I manage this?

Answer (score 3):

since you are using custom table view cells, I recommend that in your

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)
super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
```

say if you have a view as `myImageView`

dont add as:

```
addSubview(myImageView)
```

but rather add as :

```
contentView.addSubview(myImageView)
```

because contentView is the view which is automatically animated towards the right.

Answer (score 1):

During startup (-viewDidLoad or in storyboard) do:

```
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = NO;
```

Now implement the following tableView delegates

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Write code to change content insets of your cell here
    // Return YES if you want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
```

// Override to support editing the table view.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        //add code here for when you hit delete
        // Change back the content insets of cell here
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override `- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated` in your custom cells to reset constraints based on the value of editing.